# What is the CONTAINS keyword used for in MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mysql, sql

The MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual page on [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) lists `CONTAINS` as a keyword in SQL.

I was not able to find documentation to answer my question - What is the `CONTAINS` keyword for in MySQL and how is it used?

Please include links to documentation if available.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks, but no. CONTAINS is not a fuzzy match in MySQL and the link is for a question about Microsoft SQL Server which is a different database engine from MySQL.

Comment: Note that the rules governing what is and isn't considered to be a keyword (and why some of those are 'reserved') are a bit haphazard. For instance `cast` is reserved but `convert` isnt even considered a keyword.

Answer (score 3):

I've learned from [Murach's MySQL (3rd Edition)](https://www.murach.com/shop/murach-s-mysql-3rd-edition-detail) book (p. 466-467) that `CONTAINS` is part of the `CONTAINS SQL` characteristic that you can code on the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.

This is documented in the MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual page on the [`CREATE PROCEDURE` and `CREATE FUNCTION` Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) .

In this context is has an entirely different meaning from what's described in @forpas' answer above.

Comment: . . This looks like the correct answer.  It is even identified as a keyword in the statement.